# npm error code 2 in laravel project

Tags: node.js, laravel-5, npm, laravel-mix

I receive an error when running npm as below:

`npm run dev`

.
.
.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=./webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=./webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=./webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried different ways and the internet to make the script running but it keeps generating the same error.

I attached the [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwjrng2aEqueM3BsYWpZZmRmX28/view?usp=sharing).

Please advice,

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? Having a similar issue.